# Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?

Tags: c++, scope, declaration, for-loop

Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in the initialization body of a for loop in C++?

For example:

```
for(int i=0,j=0 ...
```

defines two integers. Can I define an `int` and a `char` in the initialization body? How would this be done?

Comment: It is possible in g++-4.4 (`-std=c++0x`) in the form of `for(auto i=0, j=0.0; ...`, but this possibility was removed in g++-4.5 to coincide with the c++0x texts.

Comment: Since this question pops up first for many who intent to look for the same question in C, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348766/12139179) is the C equivalent.

Comment: Note for myself: Read https://stackoverflow.com/a/2687427/5290519.

Answer (score 244, accepted):

**C++17**: **Yes!** You should use a [structured binding declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding#Case_2:_binding_a_tuple-like_type).  The syntax has been supported in gcc and clang since gcc-7 and clang-4.0 ([clang live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2D4EaSEBt5nNZmt6)). This allows us to unpack a tuple like so:

```
for (auto [i, f, s] = std::tuple{1, 1.0, std::string{"ab"}}; i < N; ++i, f += 1.5) {
    // ...
}
```

The above will give you:

- `int i` set to `1`
- `double f` set to `1.0`
- `std::string s` set to `"ab"`

Make sure to `#include <tuple>` for this kind of declaration.

You can specify the exact types inside the `tuple` by typing them all out as I have with the `std::string`, if you want to name a type. For example:

```
auto [vec, i32] = std::tuple{std::vector<int>{3, 4, 5}, std::int32_t{12}}
```

A specific application of this is iterating over a map, getting the key and value,

```
std::unordered_map<K, V> m = { /*...*/ };
for (auto& [key, value] : m) {
   // ...
}
```

See a live example [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iRd4UZsWla64rUBz)

---

**C++14**: You can do the same as C++11 (below) with the addition of type-based `std::get`. So instead of `std::get<0>(t)` in the below example, you can have `std::get<int>(t)`.

---

**C++11**: [`std::make_pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair) allows you to do this, as well as [`std::make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) for more than two objects.

```
for (auto p = std::make_pair(5, std::string("Hello World")); p.first < 10; ++p.first) {
    std::cout << p.second << '\n';
}
```

`std::make_pair` will return the two arguments in a `std::pair`.  The elements can be accessed with `.first` and `.second`.

For more than two objects, you'll need to use a `std::tuple`

```
for (auto t = std::make_tuple(0, std::string("Hello world"), std::vector<int>{});
        std::get<0>(t) < 10;
        ++std::get<0>(t)) {
    std::cout << std::get<1>(t) << '\n'; // cout Hello world
    std::get<2>(t).push_back(std::get<0>(t)); // add counter value to the vector
}
```

`std::make_tuple` is a variadic template that will construct a tuple of any number of arguments (with some technical limitations of course).  The elements can be accessed by index with `std::get<INDEX>(tuple_object)`

Within the for loop bodies you can easily alias the objects, though you still need to use `.first` or `std::get` for the for loop condition and update expression

```
for (auto t = std::make_tuple(0, std::string("Hello world"), std::vector<int>{});
        std::get<0>(t) < 10;
        ++std::get<0>(t)) {
    auto& i = std::get<0>(t);
    auto& s = std::get<1>(t);
    auto& v = std::get<2>(t);
    std::cout << s << '\n'; // cout Hello world
    v.push_back(i); // add counter value to the vector
}
```

---

**C++98 and C++03** You can explicitly name the types of a `std::pair`. There is no standard way to generalize this to more than two types though:

```
for (std::pair<int, std::string> p(5, "Hello World"); p.first < 10; ++p.first) {
    std::cout << p.second << '\n';
}
```

Comment: If you are doing C++17, you can even drop the `make_` and write `std::pair(1, 1.0)`.

Comment: The hairy C++14 style tuple / pair business -- all good (probably, upvoted), but looks bizarre :)

Comment: In short:Yes it's possible, but not going to be pretty.

Comment: I understand this is "idiomatic" C++ (at the time around C++17, at least), but by the gods that's really ugly. The whole `std` namespace living in pretension it's part of the language, is just one giant step in the wrong direction, leaped too far, in my opinion.

Comment: At this point, I'd forget about the whole declaring-multiple-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop-initialization-thing and just declare them before the loop.

Answer (score 317):

No - but technically there is a work-around (not that i'd actually use it unless forced to):

```
for(struct { int a; char b; } s = { 0, 'a' } ; s.a < 5 ; ++s.a) 
{
    std::cout << s.a << " " << s.b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: with c++11 I you can make this example shorter using default values `struct { int a=0; char b='a'; } s;`

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: That's so ugly, variables scatters around.

Comment: Thanks for this. I just sat here maniacally laughing to myself over: 

`for(struct { std::vector<float>::iterator it; size_t count; } v { vec.begin(), 1 }; v.it < vec.end(); ++v.it, ++v.count) { ... }`

Answer (score 250):

Not possible, but you can do:

```
float f;
int i;
for (i = 0,f = 0.0; i < 5; i++)
{
  //...
}
```

Or, explicitly limit the scope of `f` and `i` using additional brackets:

```
{
    float f; 
    int i;
    for (i = 0,f = 0.0; i < 5; i++)
    {
       //...
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is a very old question, but can you explain why some would do it with the extra brackets around it, as in your second example?

Comment: @fizzisist to explicitly limit the scope of f and i to only parts of the code where they are used.

Comment: @MK. Thanks, that's what I suspected. I edited your answer to explain that.

Comment: Only one question: Why like this? :O

Comment: Because it works like 'int a = 0, b = 4', I assume. That being said, scoping f and i will likely be useful only to prevent reusing those names (which is a fair reason), but the generated code will typically be the same on a modern compiler (in this case).

Comment: But this will make your indentation ugly as hell.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, IMO. 

Using structured bindings of a tuple (etc), just to limit scope, is very obtuse. Just use curly braces if you want / need to limit scope. That's what they are there for.

Answer (score 15):

You can't declare multiple types in the initialization, but you can assign to multiple types E.G.

```
{
   int i;
   char x;
   for(i = 0, x = 'p'; ...){
      ...
   }
}
```

Just declare them in their own scope.

Comment: But this will make your indentation ugly as hell.

Answer (score 3):

I think best approach is [xian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866034/7354469).

but...

---

## # Nested for loop

This approach is dirty, but can solve at all version.

so, I often use it in macro functions.

```cpp
for(int _int=0, /* make local variable */ \
    loopOnce=true; loopOnce==true; loopOnce=false)

    for(char _char=0; _char<3; _char++)
    {
        // do anything with
        // _int, _char
    }
```

#### Additional 1.

It can also be used to `declare local variables` and `initialize global variables`.

```cpp
float globalFloat;

for(int localInt=0, /* decalre local variable */ \
    _=1;_;_=0)

    for(globalFloat=2.f; localInt<3; localInt++) /* initialize global variable */
    {
        // do.
    }
```

#### Additional 2.

Good example : with macro function.

(If [best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/866034/7354469) can't be used because it is a for-loop-macro)

```cpp
#define for_two_decl(_decl_1, _decl_2, cond, incr) \
for(_decl_1, _=1;_;_=0)\
    for(_decl_2; (cond); (incr))


    for_two_decl(int i=0, char c=0, i<3, i++)
    {
        // your body with
        // i, c
    }
```

---

## # If-statement trick

```cpp
if (A* a=nullptr);
else
    for(...) // a is visible
```

If you want initialize to `0` or `nullptr`, you can use this trick.

but I don't recommend this because of hard reading.

and it seems like bug.

Comment: Note that "break" and "continue" will not work as expected here.

Comment: @Michaël: Why? Wouldn't one continue the inner-most `for` in all of the examples?

Comment: There's also: ```for(int i = 0; i < whatever; i++) if (A & a = get_a(i))``` that does not break `break` and `continue` and is transparent. The downside is that A must implement an explicit operator bool returning true.

Comment: excellent `if` statement trick, thanks

Answer (score 0):

See  "[Is there a way to define variables of two types in for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866012/is-there-a-way-to-define-variables-of-two-types-in-for-loop)" for another way involving nesting multiple for loops. The advantage of the other way over Georg's "struct trick" is that it (1) allows you to have a mixture of static and non-static local variables and (2) it allows you to have non-copyable variables. The downside is that it is far less readable and may be less efficient.

Answer (score -3):

Also you could use like below in C++.

```
int j=3;
int i=2;
for (; i<n && j<n ; j=j+2, i=i+2){
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score -6):

Define a macro:

```
#define FOR( typeX,x,valueX,  typeY,y,valueY,  condition, increments) typeX x; typeY y; for(x=valueX,y=valueY;condition;increments)

FOR(int,i,0,  int,f,0.0,  i < 5, i++)
{
  //...
}
```

Just remember, your variable scopes will not be within the for loop this way either.

Comment: You could easily overcome that limitation by wrapping the code in the macro in a separate scope using `{` and `}`.

Comment: No he couldn't.  His macro doesn't wrap the loop body.  He could add an extra openning bracket, but that would require an "extra" closing bracket when using the macro.

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I would sooner use any of the other answers before considering this.