# Java - comma operator outside for loop declaration

Tags: java, for-loop, variable-assignment, assignment-operator, comma-operator

I know I can use the comma operator like this

```
for (int i = 1, j = 15; j>10; i++, j--) {
    // do something neat
}
```

but some articles seem to suggest that the comma operator can be used outside of the for loop declaration, for example

```
int j = 2, k = 4 ;
int x ;
// Assignment statement with comma operator
x = j + 1, k ;
```

source: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/comma.html

or

```
int x = (expression) ? (i++,2) : 3;
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12047433/1084813

This would be a neat trick for a code obfuscation contest or to confuse my colleagues, but neither of the examples will compile (Java 1.6, Eclipse Juno), the error is "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable". I tried looking at the compiler settings to see whether it could be forbidden to prevent bad code, but without luck.

What's wrong? Was the comma operator a part of an older specification which later changed? Are the people that wrote those examples using a different Java setup that allows this?

Comment: The JLS says: [Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no comma operator.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

Comment: "or to confuse my colleagues".  Most people try to make their code MORE readable, not less.

Comment: Its incorrect syntax, also why would you want to confuse your collegues? The code will become legacy soon enough without extra obfuscation efforts.

Comment: Confuse only for fun, of course, not to be used in serious code. The compiler says that "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable"

Comment: Don't do that, the readability is messed up.

Comment: Can we introduce a "confusion" tag, please?

Comment: @Jesper: I know about this, but both examples are from places related to Java, are you suggesting that both authors were just C programmers in disguise?

Comment: @JohnEye As you noticed the Java compiler doesn't accept it, so it isn't valid Java code. Probably the people who wrote that mistakenly thought that the comma operator was another C feature which Java also has.

Comment: @Jesper: I would be happy to accept that as likely, but the fact that it is taken from a university lecture materials won't let me. Surely some student would notice that this isn't a valid code :-/

Comment: @JohnEye I understand but the Java Language Specification is the official source, so if that says there's no comma operator, then I tend to believe that the university lecture is wrong.

Comment: @JohnEye It doesn't matter where you got it from, or why the authors were wrong, unless it was a normative reference. In this case the only normative reference is the JLS, and it says otherwise.

Comment: @JohnEye, the second source you've pointed (on SO) doesn't exist anymore :(

Comment: @Ehsan: The answer was probably downvoted out of existence because it was wrong. Using a comma like this is simply not correct and will not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's wrong?

Some of the tricks which work in C don't work in Java.

> Was the comma operator a part of an older specification which later changed?

This never worked in Java AFAIK.

> Are the people that wrote those examples using a different Java setup that allows this?

Its a common mistake to assume Java is just like C or C++ because it is similar. A good portion of coding mistakes on SO are due to people trying to write C++ in Java and getting confused when it doesn't do what they expect.

BTW: I have made the same mistake assuming C++ is just like Java as my knowledge of C++ is not current.

---

However some tricks which working Java but perhaps not C.

You can use all currency symbols or which there are a few which look at most the same.

e.g.

```
if( ⁀ ‿ ⁀ == ⁀ ⁔ ⁀ || ¢ + ￠== ₡)
```

You can use character which are invisible and c couple which reverse the order the rest of the line when printed. ;)

This program compiles and runs and prints all the odd characters you can use in Java identifiers

```
for (char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
    if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h))
        System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
```

which makes its almost too easy.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/uses-for-special-characters-in-java-code.html

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html

Comment: "This would be a neat trick for a code obfuscation contest or to confuse my colleagues,"

Comment: "Some of the trick which work in C don't work in Java." Not sure there is much more you can say.

Comment: The first example was taken from an article about Java and the second one was found under a Java related question on SO! This is not just some C code that I'm trying to make work in Java.

Comment: @JohnEye Hopefully that is a better attempt at answering your questions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey If I search using the term "connecting character" on JLS nothing shows up. Where did you find these information?

Comment: @iamcreasy the correct term is "connector punctuation" http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks. But "connector punctuation" doesn't yield any result on JSL too.

Answer (score 13):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27

> ***15.27. Expression***
>
> *<...>*
>
> *Unlike C and C++, the Java programming language has no comma operator.*

Comment: Java has comma separator. [Source : JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.11)

Comment: @iamcreasy java doesnt have a comma operator its only a seperator. In your source its given that its a seperator and not an operator. There's a difference.