# why do we not have multiple initialization in for loop? we do have multiple increment statements

Tags: java

why do we not have multiple initialization in for loop? we do have multiple increment statements.

code:

```
for(int i=1,int c=4;i<1;i++)
  System.out.println(c);
```

This code shows a compile time error.

Comment: Wrong syntax: `for (int i=1, c=4; i < 1; i++)`

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple increment statements like `i++, c++` but not `i + 1, c + 1` which lies in the nature of transforming a for loop into "normal" code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Initialize multiple variables in for loop init?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542871/java-initialize-multiple-variables-in-for-loop-init)

Comment: WHAT error? Your compiler usually gives a detailed error message, it is very helpful for others if you copy and paste these error messages verbatim when asking a question! (And sometimes, you may even answer the question yourself...)

Comment: but it's sad that `for (int i, char c; ...` is not working, in such cases I use `while`...

Answer (score 6):

You are using wrong syntax.
You can use this way

```
  for(int i=1, c=4;i<1;i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

If by "have multiple increment statements" you mean e.g.

```
for(int i=1, c=4;i<1;i++,c++)
//                   ^   ^
//                   |   |
// Multiple increment expressions
```

First of all, they are *expressions* and not statements. Secondly, `i++,c++` is *one* expression, using the comma operator to separate two sub-expressions.