# declaring different type variables inside for condition in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, definition

I know this is stupid, but it is sort of hard to research properly due to it's simple nature, I suppose.

```
for (char letter = 'a', int num = 1; maxLine - num > 0; letter++, num++) {
    System.out.print(letter);
}
```

This is a standard way to define variables inside a for condition for C and C#, but it doesn't seem to work here. Why?

Comment: can u ever define `int i =0 ,char c ='a';`?, don't think it works in c++ or c#

Comment: Please don't add meta-tags like "<solved>" to titles. The correct way is to accept an answer, or - if the question hadn't been closed - posting your own answer (if none of the current answers suffice) and accepting it after the cooldown period.

Comment: This question was wrongly closed. Its not a duplicate(or at least the duplicate cross is wrong coz that question refers to c++ not java).

Answer (score 1):

Because the variable declaration in a `for` loop follows that of [*local variable declaration*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542871/java-initialize-multiple-variables-in-for-loop-init).

Similar to how the following is not valid as a local declaration because it contains multiple types:

```
char letter = 'a', int num = 1;
```

It is also not valid in a for loop. You can, however, define multiple variables of the same type:

```
for (int n = 0, m = 5; n*m < 400; n++) {}
```

As to why the designers made it that way, ask them if you see them.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work in C/C++ either, not sure about C#, though.

The first part of your for statement might have multiple variables, but with the same type. The reason for this is that it is generally not possible to write:

```
int n = 0, char c = 5;
```

If you would like to do this, you needed two statements. Similarly, the first part of `for` only accepts one statement, so that you cannot put two ones in here.