# for loop's init-statement with two types of variable

Tags: c++

I want to declare two types of variables in for's init-statement. like the following codes. I know "for (string word, int numb, ; cin>>word>>numb; )" is not working. just trying to let you know what I am trying to do. My goal is to declare two types of variables with the same lifetime and cin them together. Other way of coding is helpful too. thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    cout<<"enter a word and a number"<<endl;
    for (string word, int numb, ; cin>>word>>numb; )
    {
        //do some work      
    }
return 0;
}
```

ok, I think this is the closest I can get as someone suggested.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    vector<pair<string,int> > pvec;
    cout<<"enter a word and a number"<<endl;
    {
        int numb=0; 
        for (string word; cin>>word>>numb; )
            pvec.push_back(make_pair(word,numb));
    }
    cout<<pvec[3].second<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: what isn't working?  is it failing to compile?  Is it compiling but giving incorrect results?

Comment: for (string word, int numb, ; cin>>word>>numb; )
this statement. because "string" wants to declara int as a variable too.

Comment: In future posts please post **complete**, minimal sample programs.  While your program is minimal, it is not complete. Why make all of us re-type the three missing header lines, instead of posting it yourself? See http://sscce.org for more information about complete, minimal sample programs.

Comment: @Rob: Generally, I agree.  In this instance, it's fairly clear (at least to me) that the above code is syntactically invalid, and the OP wants to know if such a thing is possible.

Comment: Thanks, @OliCharlesworth. Even in this case, I was curious to see the exact error message -- which required more than a simple copy, paste, compile on my part.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  yes, I am thinking if it's possible to do it

Comment: Thanks, @ihm. I find people get better and quicker answers if they take this particular first step.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About the nearest you can get is:

```
int main ()
{
    cout<<"enter a word and a number"<<endl;
    {
        string word;
        for (int numb; cin>>word>>numb; )
        {
            //do some work      
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The extra set of braces limits the scope of `word` similarly to the way the loop limits the scope of `numb`.  Clearly, you could reverse the declarations; it might be better (more symmetric) to use:

```
int main ()
{
    cout<<"enter a word and a number"<<endl;
    {
        string word;
        int numb;
        while (cin>>word>>numb)
        {
            //do some work      
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Since there is no increment or initialize operation, the code is really a while loop with a couple of declared variables; this achieves the same result and works.

Comment: great. I think it's the closest one. it doesn't look clean, kinda bulky though. (not trying to be an @ss). just saying

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.  You can declare two variables of the same basic type in the initialization statement in the for loop, but you cannot declare two variables of different basic types.  You have to declare one outside of the for loop.

Comment: Actually he can declare a struct containing both of those variables

Comment: He could, but is there really a reason to create a struct for two items that have nothing to do with each other?  The right answer here is not to use a for loop, not to encourage questionable programming practice as a workaround to syntax.

Comment: That's declaring one variable of one type.  Also, I find that notion offensive to the senses.  If I ever saw a struct defined inside a for-loop initialization block in a code review, I would read the person who did it the riot act.

Comment: This is incorrect. `for (int a, *b, &c;...` has 3 different types.

Comment: A rather classic use of `struct` (i.e. combining several variables together) if there ever was one. Personally I probably wouldn't do it, but I wouldn't complain either.

Comment: @Pubby Well played.  I meant to say *basic* types.  Corrected.

Comment: Right, I was just saying it is a possibility :) I would hate to see that too in the code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain it's not possible to declare 2 variables of 2 different types in a for statement, but I also fail to see the advantage to doing so over something like this:

```
int main ()
{
    cout<<"enter a word and a number"<<endl;
    while( cin.good() )
    {
        string word;
        int num;

        cin >> word >> num;
        //do some work      
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In general I prefer to use for loops where there is something to count or at least iterate over.  Other situations should be using a while or do loop.

Comment: Your check is in the wrong place -- or you must have another. Your current code doesn't check whether the read operation was successful or not (and it's a *good* idiom to use stream operations as a condition).

Comment: It gets the idea across, I would claim.  Especially as the OP asked about declaration syntax, not stream usage.

Comment: yes, this one works. but it doesn't look as clean as for loop. and this takes a lot space.

Comment: "Space taken" is a pretty awful measure for code readability, and has 0 to do with efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying to do it is not the cleanest way. I'd do it like this:

```
string word;
int num;
while(true)
{
    cin >> word >> num;
    if (!cin.good()) break;
    // do some work
}
```

`word` and `num` are in the same scope (same "lifetime")

Note that you'd want to substitute the `while(true)` with some suitable condition.

---

If you want word and num to be inside the scope of the loop do something like:

```
while(true)
{
    string word;
    int num;
    cin >> word >> num;
    if (!cin.good()) break;
    // do some work
}
```

OR

```
{
    string word;
    int num;
    while(true)
    {
        cin >> word >> num;
        if (!cin.good()) break;
        // do some work
    }
}
```

I don't know why this would be necessary though.

Comment: yes, this works, but word and num still exist after the while loop is over

Comment: If the OP's syntax were valid, it would arguably be cleaner; it would limit the scope of the variables to the loop.

Comment: Then put them inside the scope of the loop. See my edit. Its stack allocation anyways.

Comment: Now that's just stupid, refactoring a good test (i.e. stream operation's successfulness) out of the loop condition, and *not* testing the status of the stream at all.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, I want to make it cleaner and easy to move around.

Comment: @jil, it's not checking cin status

Comment: @eq- @ihm Did you not see: "Note that you'd want to substitute the while(true) with some suitable condition." Meaning `cin.good()`, etc..

Comment: But you *can't* substitute while(true), the condition would be in the wrong place (i.e. before read operation). It's still in the wrong place in 1 of your examples.

Answer (score 1):

The following is untested, but should work:

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << "enter a word and a number" << endl;
  for (struct { std::string word, int number } vars;
       std::cin >> vars.word >> vars.number;
      )
  {
    //do some work      
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: At least on VS 2010 it does not work. Although a quick look at the C++ grammar says it should be allowed, so maybe it's a bug in VS. edit: g++ allows it.

Comment: Link to microsoft connect bug on this issue: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/624410/visual-c-compiler-fails-to-parse-a-for-init-statement-that-starts-with-a-class-specifier

Answer (score 0):

Since c++17:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    for (auto && [w,i] =  std::tuple{std::string{},int{}} ; std::cin >> w >> i ; )
        std::cout << "word " << w << " number " << i << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```