# Declaring several new counters in a for loop

Tags: c++, c, stl

Consider the following code:

```
vector<int> v;
for(vector<int>::iterator vi = n.begin(), int i = 0;
    vi != n.end();
    ++vi, ++i){}
```

Is there a reason why this is not allowed? I want to be able to define 2 new counters, both vi and the index i.

Comment: The standard forbids it.

Comment: Excellent answer Luchian. Can you expand?

Comment: You can declare multiple objects of the same type, but not of different types. The allowed syntax is `for(T a=x, b=y, c=z; ...)`. Can't really say why.

Comment: A closely related (duplicate?) topic can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8783896/1945549. For what it's worth you can of course declare one or both counters before the loop and it'll work. But that isn't satisfying in terms of keeping the variables local to the loop.

Comment: Are you interested in workarounds or just want to know the reason this is not allowed?

Comment: @jrok Both, really. I don't really udnerstand why this is not allowed and, on the topic of workaroudn, I assume you can just define the variable outside (but that's a bit inelegant)

Comment: Duplicate. [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100051/for-loops-init-statement-with-two-types-of-variable)

Comment: If you really want to initialise it in the `for` statement then you can use a `tuple`: `for (auto i = std::make_tuple(n.begin(), 0); ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the explanation from the book *C++ Primer*:

> As in any other declaration, init-statement can define several objects. However, **init-statement may be only a single declaration statement.** Therefore, all the variables must have the same base type. As one example, we might write a loop to duplicate the elements of a `vector` on the end as follows:
>
> ```
> // remember the size of v and stop when we get to the original last element
>
> for (decltype(v.size()) i = 0, sz = v.size(); i != sz; ++i)
>
>     v.push_back(v[i]);
> ```
>
> In this loop we define both the index, `i`, and the loop control, `sz`, in init-statement.

This makes sense, the syntax of `for` loop is:

> #### C++11 §6.5.3 The for statement [stmt.for]
>
> The `for` statement
>
> ```
> for ( for-init-statement ; condition opt ; expression opt ) statement
> ```

`for-init-statement` is one statement only. Declaration two different types of variables would make it at least two statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use two variables of differing type in a for loop, one must be declared outside the scope of the for loop. You can enforce the scope of the second one by enclosing the loop inside a set of braces:

```
vector<int> v;
{
int i = 0;
for(vector<int>::iterator vi = n.begin(); vi != n.end(); ++vi, ++i) { /* DO STUFF */ }
} //i's scope ends here.
```

Comment: "may _not_ be used elsewhere"*

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a reason why this is not allowed?

Because the arcane declaration syntax of C++ doesn't allow you to declare objects of unrelated types in the same declaration statement; and the initialiser of a `for` loop only allows a single declaration statement.

> I want to be able to define 2 new counters, both `vi` and the index `i`.

You could declare one or both outside the loop, if you don't mind polluting the surrounding block. Otherwise, you could put them in a stucture:

```
for (struct {vector<int>::iterator vi; int i;} x = {n.begin(), 0}; 
     x.vi != n.end();
     ++x.vi, ++x.i) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "there isn't really any reason other than the syntax requires it".

I can imagine, though, that code could get very complex if it were allowed, so that's a good reason not to add support for this into the language.

You can create your own scope to bound it instead:

```
std::vector<int> v;
{
   std::vector<int>::iterator it = n.begin(), end = n.end();
   int i = 0;

   for ( ; it != end; ++it, ++i)
   {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only write one declaration statement, but it
can define multiple variables, e.g.:

```
for ( int i = 0, j = 10 ; ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

A look at the [comma operator wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) would help, specifically the first example.

```
int a=1, b=2, c=3, i=0; // comma acts as separator in this line, not as an operator
```

Also, why not do something like this?

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int>::iterator vi = n.begin();
int i = 0;
for(; vi != n.end(); ++vi, ++i)
{
}
```