# Can I have different types in the init-expression of a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, types, for-loop, c++11

The following code will not compile:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    for (int i = 0, double j = 0; i < 10; ++i, j+=.1){
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to initialize two different types, or do I need to create a struct/pair/etc?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You *can* inline a struct, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Is it necessary that the scope be limited to the loop?  Would it be an acceptable alternative to just put gratuitous braces around the `for` loop?

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

But you can define an anonymous struct right there as:

```
for (struct { int i; double j; } x = {0,0};  x.i < 10; ++x.i, x.j+=.1)
{
    std::cout << x.i << " " << x.j << '\n';
}
```

See the initialization part:

```
struct { int i; double j; } x = {0,0};
```

It defines an anonymous struct, then creates an object `x` and initializes it with `{0,0}` which initializes both members `i` and `j` with `0`.

Comment: It does not compile for me on VC++ :O, does it for you?

Comment: @Saqlain: Yes. [See yourself here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=6bd36fc4b91846b1084d84207525b5a3-61c3814520a8d4318f681038dc4b4da7).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/889001/34509

Comment: On VS 2005 i get below error with above code error C2332: 'struct' : missing tag name
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
warning C4094: untagged 'struct' declared no symbols
error C2059: syntax error : 'empty declaration'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'
error C2065: 'x' : undeclared identifier
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'

Comment: @Saqlain: That means MSVC2005 has bug.

Comment: Yep, that can be true!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, but there is way:

```
double var1;
int var2;
for (var2 = 0,var1 = 0.0; var2 < 12; var2++){}
```

If you want to limit scope of f and i then enclose them in {}, just like

```
{
    double var1;
    int var2;
    for (var2 = 0,var1 = 0.0; var2 < 12; var2++){}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can have multiple variables, but they have to be the same type.

Answer (score 0):

They have to be the same type, but you can use structs to bypass that.

```
for (struct {int j; char i;} loop = {0, 'e'}; loop.i < 33; ++loop.j, ++loop.i)
{
    std::cout << loop.i << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do the following

```
#include<cstdlib>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int i; double j;
    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < 10; ++i, j+= .1){
        std::cout << i << " " << j << '\n';
    }


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```