# Declare two different variables in for loop where one is a non-movable, non-copyable object

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm aware of declaring and initializing two different variables in a for loop with a `std::pair` or an anonymous `struct` type, but [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop) do not work for my purposes.

Let's say I have the following class definition

```
class Object {
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        Object(int i) : i(i) { }
        // everything else deleted
        Object() = delete;
        Object(const Object &) = delete;
        Object(Object &&) = delete;
        Object & operator=(const Object &) = delete;
        Object & operator=(Object &&) = delete;
};
```

Is there any way I can initialize an `Object` and an `int` in the  `for` loop line.  I don't want to add an extra block around the for loop or anything like that.  I am okay with `std::tuple`, `std::pair`, anonymous `structs`, whatever, just so long as it has the form

```
for(/* creates Object and int*/ ; /*whatever*/; /*whatever*/) { /* ... */}
```

or (if the syntax existed)

```
for( Object o(69), int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { /* ... */ }
```

What I do not want is an extra **named** class definition.  I have come up with this already:

```
for(class Container : private Object {
            public:
                int value;
                Container(int i) : Object(i), value(0) { }
                } container(69); /* ... */ ;
        container.value < 10;
        ++container.value) { /* ... */}
```

But the class name `Container` then becomes visible inside of the for loop, which I am trying to avoid.

My *actual* use of this is a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>` and a `bool`, so that the mutex is released after exiting the loop.

Comment: No need to delete the move functions if you already delete the copying versions.

Comment: This question is super vague.  Why not just `for(/*whatever*/) {int i; Object o; /*code*/}`?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @MooingDuck yes, perhaps too vague, sorry about that.  Doing the above would create a new `i` and `o` on each iteration, as opposed to the normal for loop variable declarations.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The `int i; Object o;` should be put *outside* of the for-loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [piecewise construction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct_t) to invoke the constructors:

```
for (std::pair<Object, int> x (std::piecewise_construct,
                               std::make_tuple(69),
                               std::make_tuple(0));
     x.second < 10; x.second ++) {

    std::cout << x.first.i << "/" << x.second << std::endl;
    x.first.i += 4;
}
```

Unfortunately this does not generalize to tuples. There is no piecewise constructor for `std::tuple`.

---

Not sure why you disregard it, but I find the "pair" solution is very ugly compared to the more straight-forward implementation

```
{
    Object o (69);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++ i) {
        std::cout << o.i << "/" << i;
        o.i += i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with [`optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/emplace):

```
#include <utlility>

std::optional<Object> o;

for ( ; ; )
{
    o.emplace(12);
}
```

(This is available in C++14, but also from `<boost/optional.hpp>`.)

Comment: OP clarified question slightly