# How to iterate through a std::map<string,int> and std::vector<int> using single for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, vector, stdmap

How to iterate through a `std::map<string,int>` and `std::vector<int>` using single `for` loop ?

I have seen [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2687392/1691223) but could not solve my problem.

I am trying like this

```
map<string,int> data;
data["Shravan"] = 1;
data["Mama"] = 2;
data["Sa1"] = 3;
data["Jhandu"] = 4;

vector<int> values = {1,2,3,4};

for(const auto& it1: data,it2 : values) {
    // Do something 
}
```

**Edit** :  I can not go through one by one. Because i am using the key of `std::map` and value of `std::vector` in the same function. Which will be called inside `for` loop.

Both the container of same size.

Comment: Why?? And what behaviour do you want; go through one container then the other? Or can they be interleaved?

Comment: have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/begin/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/ , but it is to be noted, that this is not a good practice... Similar functionality also applies to vectors

Comment: @BoBTFish : I can not go through one by one. Because i am using the key of `std::map` and value of `std::vector` in the same function.

Comment: There are may good answers, I wish i could accept all. But I have to obey the SO rules, hence accepting one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know there's both the same length, use something like:

```
auto vit = begin(value);
auto mit = begin(data);
for (; vit != end(value); ++mit, ++vit) {
    // Use mit and vit
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. `mit` is a reference to _const_ and `++` operator is not const.

Comment: Modified answer appropriately

Answer (score 2):

How about a do-while? Provided that your containers aren't empty.

```
auto iv = std::begin(value);
auto id = std::begin(data);

do {
    // Use those iterators
} while(++iv != std::end(value) && ++id != std::end(data))
```

Or use `while` if you'd like to handle empty containers too.

```
auto iv = std::begin(value);
auto id = std::begin(data);

while(iv != std::end(value) && id != std::end(data)) {
    // Use those iterators

    iv++; id++;
}
```

Comment: A simple `while` handle empty containers.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, my code fails on empty ones. Added it as a pre-condition :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider `boost::zip_iterator` discussed in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513803/2210478

Comment: @MikeMB Yes, you're right. The code I suggested is wrong. I've removed it. Maybe OP can check the zip_iterator  still.

Comment: Ok, removed the down vote. If you add a usage example you get an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over both the `map` and the `vector` and make sure to check the iterators against the end of the corresponding container.

```
auto map_iter = data.begin();
auto vec_iter = value.begin();
for (; map_iter != data.end() && vec_iter != value.end();
       ++map_iter, ++vec_iter) {
    // Use map_iter and vec_iter
}
```