# error: assignment of read-only reference ‘it’?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `std::map<string, int>` and `std::vector<vector<double>>`. I have to iterate both the container at the same time [doing this way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42154103/1691223). And i would like to update the value of 2-D `std::vector`.

```
map<string,int> portfolioCategories = optimizationPortfolioCategories();
vector<vector<double>> coVarianceMatrix(numberOfCategory,vector<double>(numberOfCategory));
auto map_itr = portfolioCategories.begin();
auto vec_itr = coVarianceMatrix.begin();
for(; map_itr != portfolioCategories.end() && vec_itr != coVarianceMatrix.end(); map_itr++, vec_itr++) {
    for(const auto& it: (*vec_itr))
        it = coVariance(monthlyReturnFundCategory[index],monthlyReturnFundCategory[count]);
}
```

How can I iterate over both the container at the same time, so that i can update the value of 2D vector.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @Shravan40 You used `const` there for a reason? Also range based for loop values usually aren't iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Const values cannot be assigned to. Since you declared `it` as `const auto&`, you cannot assign to `it`. In order to be able to assign to `it`, you need to declare it non-const:

```
for (auto& it : *vec_itr)
//   ^^^^^^^^
//   not const
```