# Can you use 2 different types of variables in a for loop in c++?

Tags: c++

Sorry, still new to programming!
Is it possible to have different types of variables in a for loop?
In my example I'm wanting to use an int to represent the number and a char to represent the alphabet but I get many errors :/ I was hoping to get;
" #1 in the alphabet is letter: a"
" #2 in the alphabet is letter: b" etc ...

Thanks!

```
    for (int i{ 1 }, char alphabet{ 'a' }; int >= 26; i++, alphabet++ )
        {
            cout << "# " << i << " in the alphabet is letter: " << alphabet << endl;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: There's also a type in your code: `int >= 26` should be `i <= 26`

Comment: For your particular case you can use a single variable `i` and the character is `'a'+i-1`

Comment: Thanks for you responses! I noticed when i went back to VS i had the int >= rather than  i <= . I got it working by having the alphabet variable declared before the loop the incremented it inside the loop