# C++: How to use a 'for' loop to multiply 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a program to populate two multidimensional arrays and multiply their elements using for loops only. The code's pretty simple yet I'm stuck with a host of errors from the multiplication loop. I can't wrap my head around this one.

[image: the log]

Is there a problem with my loop syntax? I'll attach the code below. Lines 48 and 49 are the loop code for multiplication. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Creating array: " << endl;

cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Please enter the number of rows: "; 
int numRows2 = 0;
cin >> numRows2;

cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Please enter the number of columns: ";
int numCols2 = 0;
cin >> numCols2;

double myNums2[numRows2][numCols2];

for (int counter = 0; counter < numRows2; counter++)
    {
        for (int counter_a = 0; counter_a < numCols2; counter_a++)
           {
            cout << "Enter Element [" << counter << "][" << counter_a << "]: ";
            cin >> myNums2[counter][counter_a];
            }
    }

cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Displaying contents of the array: " << endl;

for (int counter = 0; counter < numRows2; ++counter)
    {
        for (int counter_a = 0; counter_a < numCols2; ++counter_a)

            cout << "Element [" << counter <<"][" << counter_a << "]: " << myNums2[counter][counter_a] << endl;
    }


cout << " " << endl;

cout << "Multiplying each element in myNums1 by each element in myNums2: " << endl;

for (int indexRow1 = 0, int indexCol1 = 0; indexRow1 < numRows, indexCol1 < numCols; ++indexRow1, ++indexCol1)
    for (int indexRow2 = 0, int indexCol2; indexRow2 < numRows2, indexCol2 < numCols2; ++indexRow2, ++indexCol2)
        {
            cout << myNums1[indexRow1][indexRow2] << " x " << myNums2[indexRow2][indexCol2] << " = " << myNums1[indexRow1][indexCol1] * myNums2[indexRow2][indexCol2] << endl;
        }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cin >> numCols2; double myNums2[numRows2][numCols2];` is a VLA and is not valid C++. Use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Comment: That syntax works perfectly when I comment out the multiplication code. This specific project requires the use of arrays.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that the project *requires* you to use invalid code. Are you sure that `vector` is not allowed? If so, maybe you're supposed to dynamically allocate the arrays, or maybe you can create arrays with a constant size that will not be exceeded.

Comment: I'll have to double-check the project requirements... I may have misread something. Using std::vector and dynamically allocating the arrays is the better solution.

Comment: In the last 'cout': myNums1[R1][R2] << " x " << myNums2[R2][C2]   =  myNums1[R1][C1] * myNums2[R2][C2]. The indexes is knid of mixed. Is that you intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not declare two variables in the `for` loop as you are doing it.
You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop) for ways to achieve it.

On the snippet you share, certain variables are not declared, `numRows`, `numCols`, `myNums1`.

`indexCols2` is not initialized, even though the for loop is not correct as it is.

As @cigien mentioned in the comment, to use an array you will have to allocate memory dynamically if you want to read the size from the user.

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your code at the `for` loops:

```
for (int indexRow1 = 0, int indexCol1 = 0; indexRow1 < numRows, indexCol1 < numCols; ++indexRow1, ++indexCol1)
    for (int indexRow2 = 0, int indexCol2; indexRow2 < numRows2, indexCol2 < numCols2; ++indexRow2, ++indexCol2)
```

- First: This declaration is wrong

```
for (int indexRow1 = 0, int indexCol1 = 0, ...)
```

```
The correct one is:
```

```
for (int indexRow1 = 0, indexCol1 = 0, ...)
```

- Second: You didn't declare `numRows` and `numCols` before the `for` loop. You may need to check your code and declare them.