# Why there is a limitation that c++ 'auto' cannot stand for multiple types

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I mean, why the following example is not a valid construction:

```
if (auto x = 2, y = "ab"; x != 0) {
  // ...
}
```

(In my real use case there are calls to some functions instead of `2` and `"ab"` literals.)

or

```
std::vector<int> cont1;
std::vector<char> cont2;
for (auto it1 = cont1.begin(), it2 = cont2.begin(); it1 != cont1.end() && it2 != cont2.end(); ++it1, ++it2) {
  // ...
}
```

It seems that e.g. in the first example, Visual C++ deduces `int` for `auto` from the first `2` and then it reports: `"ab"` cannot initialize `int`.

But on the other side it is allowed to write:

```
if (auto [x, y] = std::make_pair(2, "ab"); x != 0) {
  // ...
}
```

So here, `auto` stands for different types.

Beside the answer "why", I'd like to know if there are any other workarounds (except the one I have above).

Comment: "*So here, auto stands for different types.*" No, it "stands for" one type: the type returned by `std::make_pair`. `x` and `y` are subobjects of that object.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Is that strictly speaking true? I can't write the actual type of `auto func = [](){return 0;};` but `auto` still deduces whatever implementation-defined type the lambda expression is.

Comment: Reason is history. When `auto` has been introduced in `C++11` it suppose to replace single type, not a multiple types. later in C++17 `auto [x, y] = tuple` was introduced to easier handle tuples and tuples only.

Comment: @NathanPierson you are absolutely right. `auto` did have a great impact and without lambdas would not be what they are and thats not the only example. comment deleted

Comment: it is really not about `auto`, different  types in initialization statement are just not allowed `int x = 0, const char *y = "asd"; ...` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So here, `auto` stands for different types.

I wouldn't interpret it that way.

The `auto` stands for `std::pair<int, char const*>`. However, the special thing here is that the name of the pair is `[a, b]`, where `a` and `b` refer to the inner members of the pair. I would really like if the language would allow typing the type of the pair explicitly.

In fact, `a` and `b` are *not* variables. They are structured bindings, and they behave a bit differently. Although that difference is getting less apparent in C++20.

So really, the `auto` here is only one type.

Another way to demonstrate my point is this:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
auto [a, b] = std::tie(x, y);
```

Even though it was `auto` and not `auto&`, `a` and `b` are references to `x` and `y`. And attempting to use `auto&` won't work since the result of `std::tie` is a prvalue.

---

However, there are places where only one `auto` might refer to different things.

Consider this:

```
auto lambda = [](auto... args) { /* ... */ };
```

Here, `auto...` is many different things, but `auto...` is different than `auto`.

Comment: Thanks for valuable comments (especially diff between variables and structured bindings). With this I could understand why this: `int x; auto a = x, *b = &x;` works. Here `auto` stands for `int` and all around works "as usually".

Comment: @JarekC that''s because C++ uses C notation for type modifiers, where pointer, reference, array notation is technically part of the name of the variable. It's quite confusing and I usually only declare one variable per statements because of that.

Answer (score 2):

For `auto` to work, compiler needs to be able to deduce the type of the variable without you telling it explicitly.

When you write `foo x,y` you are telling compiler that variables `x` and `y` are both of type `foo`.

When you write `auto a,b` you are telling the compiler that it should deduce variables `a` and `b` to the same type. But compiler doesn't do implicit casting in such situation. Thus you cannot use `auto` even when it could make logical sense (e.g. `auto a = 2.0, b = 2;`).

Allowing for different types, when such syntax usually explicitly requests same type could lead to serious bugs.

---

Also, `auto [x, y] = std::make_pair(2, "ab")` - here `auto` doesn't stand for different types. `auto` gets deduced to be a pair of intiger and string.