# Is there a way to access variable declared in for loop outside of for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, variables

For example, there is a `char` named 'character' defined in a for loop. Can I possibly use the `char` outside of the for loop?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        char character = 'a'; // Char defined in for loop
    }

    std::cout<<character; // Can this be made valid?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Can I possibly use the char outside of the for loop?* -- What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?  This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) in disguise.

Comment: Why not just declare the variable in the outer scope?

Comment: No a variable is only visible within its scope.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this indirectly in C++11 and later, with a lambda:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
  std::function<char()> fun;

  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    char character = 'a'; // Char defined in for loop
    fun = [=](){ return character; };
  }

  std::cout << fun() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The outside scope cannot access `character`, but a lambda which was captured in that scope can be called, and the body of that lambda has `character` in scope, and can return it for us.

In a language with real lambdas, the lambda would access the actual `character` variable; the original one created in that scope. In C++, the `=` in `[=]` tells the lambda to capture the local variables it is referencing by making copies of them. Thus `return character` is not actually accessing the original `character` (which no longer exists, since the block terminated), but a copy which the lambda object carries.

Answer (score 0):

No. The scope of the variable defined inside of a loop or function is just within that loop or function.

If you want to have a variable you can set a value to in a loop but also have access to outside of the loop, you can make a global variable (or just one with a wider scope). Just define the variable outside of the scope loop and set it the value you want in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

no. because variable declared inside loop has local scope that is it can be accessed inside loop only

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you can't use it outside the loop, if the definition of the variable is inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

NO as "A variable declared within a scope can NEVER be used outside of that scope". Always keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

If you compile it with Microsoft Visual C++, you can add the option [/Zc:forScope-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-forscope-force-conformance-in-for-loop-scope?view=msvc-140) to disable conformance in for Loop Scope.

This example code is copied from the MSDN link.

```cpp
// zc_forScope.cpp
// compile by using: cl /Zc:forScope- /Za zc_forScope.cpp
// C2065, D9035 expected
int main() {
    // Compile by using cl /Zc:forScope- zc_forScope.cpp
    // to compile this non-standard code as-is.
    // Uncomment the following line to resolve C2065 for /Za.
    // int i;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        ;
    i = 20;   // i has already gone out of scope under /Za
}
```

Nevertheless, this option grants you access to the variables defined in the parenthesis of the for keyword. Variables defined in the curly brackets are still inaccessible.

If you are able to move the definition of `character` to the parenthesis, the option can help you.

```
int i = 0;
for(char character = 'a'; i < 5; i++)
{
    ...
}

std::cout<<character;
```

See also [Is it possible to declare two variables of different types in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687392/is-it-possible-to-declare-two-variables-of-different-types-in-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

variable with automatic storage duration will end its lifetime when the enclosing block ends. So when you go out of for loop, the lifetime of character has already ended.